# Airflow: How to get logged error from failed run, in calling DAG

Tags: logging, error-handling, airflow

I have a DAG that calls other DAGs using `airflow.api.client.local_client.Client.trigger_dag`. Some of these might throw an error and I want to show the error from the called DAG inside the log of the calling DAG.

I am able to get the failed task instance using the below code, but am not able to figure out how to get the logged error message.

```
            dag_runs = DagRun.find(dag_id=dag_id, run_id=dri, state="failed")
            if len(dag_runs) > 0:
                # retrieve the logs of the failed task instance
                for dag_run in dag_runs:
                    task_instances = dag_run.get_task_instances()
                    failed_task_instance = next((ti for ti in task_instances if ti.state == "failed"), None)
                    if failed_task_instance:
                        # how to get the error message?
                    raise AirflowException(f"{dag_id} DAG has failed!")
```

Comment: According to the [airflow docs](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/_api/airflow/models/taskinstance/index.html#airflow.models.taskinstance.log) each TaskInstance has a .log property

Comment: @dimButTries Yes. It returns a Logger variable, but not sure how to read the log messages from that.